# phpmyadmin gives a different result than php on same query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that record login attemps.

login:

```
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
```

every attemp with no success I record on this table.

I do a select to count last 5 minutes attemps, if it is more than 4 I use die to stop the login:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM login WHERE data > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) and ip = '100.100.100.10'
```

it is not working in phpmyadmin, return the value 0 even if I have more than 5 records.

but php works fine, returning the number of rows:

```
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

$stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM login WHERE data > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) and ip = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $ip);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

any ideas why phpmyadmin gives me one result and php another?

Comment: Are you sure your bound parameter is correct?

Comment: Maybe you mean `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: @tadman Both of us seem to be barking up the wrong tree. He says the PHP script is working, it's failing in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Things I'm questioning... 1) in the PHP, is `$ip` value `'100.100.100.10'`? (Seems like it would be easy enough to echo, print or var_dump the contents of $ip).  2) are both the app and phpmyadmin using the same database schema? is phpmyadmin looking at a `login` table in a different database?

Comment: @spencer7593 yes, the ip is 100.100.100.10 (it is a example, but it is the same as I add in phpmyadmin), and phpmyadmin always return 0.

Comment: @Barmar Good catch on the phrasing.

Comment: Are you sure the data is *literally* that string? Invisible characters can wreck your day. Does `SELECT HEX(ip) FROM login` show `3130302E3130302E3130302E3130` for that particular value? If it's anything else, like has `0A` or `20` on the end then it has empty characters in it.

Comment: maybe in the php controller you change de timezone query this `SELECT NOW();` and compare if phpadmin and php code return same time